# how to take UITable view visible paths and more rows

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Now I am taking index paths of visible tableview cells.But I want to take 3 more index path from visible rows,How can I do that ?

```
NSArray *visiblePaths = [tblView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
```

Comment: @Rachel Gallen - Thanks Rachel for edit :)

Comment: In what sense you require 3 more index paths?

Comment: how many sections in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming just one section, you can just create them, minding the max rows for that section:

```
NSMutableArray *visiblePaths = [tblView indexPathsForVisibleRows] mutableCopy];
NSInteger lastIndexPath = [visiblePaths lastObject];
NSInteger lastRow = lastIndexPath.row;
NSInteger extraRows = 3;
NSInteger maxRow = MIN(lastRow+extraRows, [self tableView:tblView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1);

for (int i = lastRow+1; i < maxRow; i++) {
    NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [visiblePaths addObject:newPath];
}
```

It's doable for more sections (and/or for rows before the first visible) also.  Hopefully it's clear how one would extend this to cover those requirements.

Comment: but what is "row"  in         NSInteger lastRow = [visiblePaths lastObject].row;

Comment: that might have been sloppy code, missing a cast.  I added a line to clarify.